What is this adapter and why is it required?
I need to replace this adapter:

that comes from an IKEA lamp:

Where it is indicated:
MODEL YZ-230/11
FOR PL LAMPS 7/9/11W
230-240V AC 50Hz 0.17A λ0.35

the lamp itself seems to be a standard FL lamp, powered by mains.
So I bet the object is not a power supply. Maybe just a 1:1 transformer? What should I search to replace it?


Any markings on the adapter itself?  Can connect IKEA or search  with the markings shown.  There a number of hits for ikea a0401.

@crip659 question updated

Do not know the language, but it seems like some kind of smart adapter/wifi/bluetooth thingy, from the last line "telecommunication"

@crip659 no smart stuff at all. It's an old lamp. I bet on transformer/ballast, etc... in other words, how would you power the lamp OSRAM DULUX S 11W/827?

@crip659 that's part of the name of the company which made it - "Tongyiang [something] Telecommunication Co Ltd".

I thought this was a DIY section of SE. Sorry, I didn't get this was off-topic. And I cannot delete the question. I apologize.

The lamp is obsolete and you should replace it with a new LED lamp.
The adapter is the control gear for the fluorescent tube.  An electronic ballast or starter.   Replacing it will require either a dangerous splice in the power cable or threading the replacement through all those metal tubes.  You won't find a new one, it looks like something custom-made for Ikea at least 20 years ago.
While replacing the lamp seems easiest to me, if you really want to replace the power pack, there seems to be some promise of finding a used lamp (It's the Ikea GLOBAL A0401) on auction sites like eBay.  Sometimes these are broken but it's usually the base or clamp that is broken so
you can combine the parts you need. Look regularly on eBay's European auction sites and similar ones in all European countries.  I had a look, there are none for sale now but they seem to come up from time to time for very little money.
I think finding a used "for parts" lamp is more probably than finding a PL fluorescent driver in the physical form you have there.  You CAN buy new drivers but they don't include an enclosure or plug or cable.  As a practical solution ... get a new lamp or find a used one for parts.

I appreciate the answer, but I'm not asking about throwing away the lamp. If I replace the OSRAM lamp with a LED one, what kind of equipment I need to use instead of the old ballast/starter in order to power it?

I updated the answer to provide I think the best way to find a replacement part.  I removed mention of LED replacement bulbs, that's really going too far ... if you need to replace the power pack AND the bulb then come on it's time for a new lamp. :)

If you want to keep the lamp, you could install some LED tape and use a suitable mains adapter (eg 12V).  LED tape is cheap, and you might already have a 12V adapter in your junk collection.

@user1908704 that's a great idea.  You should make it an answer.  It's better than mine by every measure.   The new power pack and LED strips combined will cost less than a new bulb for this lamp.  And you'll have 24V instead of 240 running up the metal arms. Or you could continue the strips all the way down the arms.  :)

Since you have a Plug in fluorescent lamp (PL). I would suggest that its a starter and ballast combination (Starters are rated in Watts).
It has Ikea on it, implying that it may have been made especially for them.  So message Ikea.

Even if it powers a common OSRAM lamp, it may be a custom object?

If it has a common brand name on it, that company ordered it and will usually be your best starting point in finding out what it was.

I do not think that contacting either IKEA or a 1990s Chinese factory are the best starting point.  Probably not good for your mental health either.

The date sticker on the lamp suggests it's the 24th week of 2008, so not that old. But I agree neither Ikea nor the factory are going to be of much help after this much time.
